# How to validate that my API Code is returning data

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I just want to know if this code I wrote is returning data and I wanted the community to help achieve it since I am new to swift, I don't know where to put the print() function just to see if data is being shown on CLI output

```
class APICaller {

static let shared = APICaller()
private let baseURL = "http://000.000.000.000:0000/api/"

private init() {}

func getVehicles(for id: String, IMEI: Int, completed: @escaping (Result<[Vehicles],OnTraErrors>) -> Void ){
    let endpoint = baseURL + "GetVehicles/?UserIdentificationValue=GASGSDG43848B497FE4604352GGS"
    
    
    let headers = [
                "content-type": "application/json",
                "authorizetoken": "NjQzODM2N0NDNDM4NDhCNDk3RkU0NjGSAG4sg3=",
                "cache-control": "no-cache",
                ]
    
    guard let url = URL(string: endpoint) else {
        completed(.failure(.invalidURL))
        return
    }
    
    var request = URLRequest(url: url, cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy, timeoutInterval: 120)
            request.httpMethod = "GET"
            request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers

    
    let session = URLSession.shared
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        
        if let _ = error {
            completed(.failure(.unableToComplete))
            return
        }
        guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse, response.statusCode == 200 else {
            completed(.failure(.invalidResponse))
            return
        }
        guard let data = data else {
            completed(.failure(.invalidData))
            return
        }
        do {
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
            let vehicles = try decoder.decode([Vehicles].self, from: data)
            completed(.success(vehicles))
        } catch {
            completed(.failure(.invalidData))
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}

}
```

Comment: After the decoding line, `print(vehicles)` perhaps or before if you only want to know `data` isn't nil. Also when decoding make sure to print and/or return the actual error.

Comment: Unrelated but rather than returning quite meaningless enum cases on `failure` return the **real** `error`s which tell you what went wrong. And `guard let data = data` will never reach the `else` scope.

Comment: @vadian should I remove the guard or how can I fix it mate :)

Comment: You can safely unwrap the optional if no error occurs